# How to load strings from different resource files depending on ComboBox selected item?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a form which changes the display language. I want to load strings from different resource files depending on a String variable, like this:

```
Public Class frm_Main

    Dim language As String = ""

    Private Sub cb_lang_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb_lang.SelectedIndexChanged
        language = cb_lang.SelectedText
        lbl_Country.Text = My.Resources.english.country ' Replace "english" with language value
        lbl_Language.Text = My.Resources.english.language ' Same
    End Sub

End Class
```

cb_lang contains "english" and "spanish".
There are two files, "english.resx" and "spanish.resx".

How can I do this?

Comment: Let the framework do the hard work. Name your resources `Foobar.resx` for default, `Foobar.en.resx` for English, `Foobar.en-UK.resx` if you need "Color" and "Armor" to look like they have a typo, have `Foobar.fr.resx` for French translations, etc. Then you just set the resources' `Culture` as appropriate (you'll need to make a `CultureInfo` instance from the selected string), and re-assign the `.Text` values. You never really need to fetch a specific language from resources - the framework does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> *There are two files, "english.resx" and "spanish.resx"*

Start with renaming the two files to `MyProject.resx` for the default culture, and `MyProject.es.resx` or `MyProject.en.resx` for the translated version.

The resource designer file is XML, but when you compile (or "run custom tool" on it) it creates/updates an actual resource class - that's the object you're accessing in code.

That object has a `CultureInfo` property that you can set to whatever `CultureInfo` you want; with the resource files properly named as per the culture codes, the framework will use that to determine which resource file to get a resource key value from.

So all you need to do is map your dropdown values to [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instances.

```
My.Resources.MyProject.Culture = SomeCultureDictionary(cb_lang.SelectedText)
lbl_Country.Text = My.Resources.MyProject.Country
lbl_Language.Text = My.Resources.MyProject.Language
```